# Составить словосочетания

Tags: словосочетания

Помогите, пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо кто ответит! Нужно  составить 10 словосочетаний, 3 с причастием, 3 с наречием, и 4 с прилагательным на правило две и одна "н" в суффиксах

Answer (score 1):

Брошенный дом, ,вязанный  бабушкой шарф,
 заштопанные носки.

Балконные решётки,соболиный мех, серебряная брошь,старинная картина

Бешено мчаться, организованно выступить,экстренно уехать